# Refresh an imageview in a listview, on click listener

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I have a custom ListView layout that contains an ImageView and two buttons; set primary and rotate image.

What I expect it behave is when a user clicked Set Primary, the set primary button will be invisible. For the rotate button, it will refresh the imageview by rotating it 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees.

All of these processes are being done by the server. So, I have a request to a web service and the response would change the state of the UI.

Here is the listview adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ...

    ItemImageModel iim = items.get(i);

    if (iim.getPrimary().equals("0")){
        vh.btnPrimary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        vh.btnPrimary.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    vh.btnRotate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(iim.getImage50()) //
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .into(vh.ivPhoto);

    vh.btnPrimary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "set primary");

        //  SetAsPrimary();
        }
    });

    vh.btnRotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "rotate");
        //  RotateImage();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

JSON response after successful primary image set:

```
{
  "results": "Successfully set primary image",
  "errors": ""
}
```

JSON response after successful image rotation. Degree is sent via POST parameter:

```
{
  "results": "Successfully set rotate image",
  "errors": ""
}
```

How do I refresh the listview with the updated UI according to the new JSON response? Do I need to refresh the ListFragment that uses this adapter? If anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You'll make your Http Asynchronous call inside of your onClickListener. Your http call should have a return callback that will get fired once there is a response from the server. In that callback, you can then update the UI accordingly. This however works only if you have an HttpClient that is set up nicely for callbacks. If you don't have one, I'd check out [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Here's a little example pseudocode:

```
 vh.btnPrimary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "set primary");
        MyHttpClient.post(Url url, MyDetails details, new MyCallback() {

            private void onSuccess(JSONBody body) {
                updateUiPrimary();
            }

            private void onFailure(JSONBody body) {
                failedApiCall();
            }
        }
    }
});

vh.btnRotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "rotate");
        MyHttpClient.post(Url url, int rotation, new MyCallback() {

            private void onSuccess(JSONBody body) {
                updateUiRotated();
            }

            private void onFailure(JSONBody body) {
                failedApiCall();
            }
        }        
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how you make your post calls, or how you post parameters to the server, so I put in dummy arguments url, details, body, etc. It will differ based on how you implement http calls

Comment: I already got the asynchronous calls part. Sorry if I mistakenly wrote the wrong question, but my question is how do I update the UI state, the single row that needs to be updated on clicked?

Comment: If the callback is located in the adapter for the individual row, the callback will have access to the image in that row. Your other option is onClick, store the position of the row being updated, and then on the callback access that position in the adapter and update the view.

Answer (score 0):

Every time user clicks call the async task to fetch the desired image and the fetch that image to the adapter. You have to use case statement in that you might create 4 async task or pass the url to the async task.